# std::string, why this behaviour of the range constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code which loads text file contents into a char *. (I know it's an odd mix of C++ and C but please bear with me.)

```
std::ifstream filestream1(filename);

std::string str1(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream1), 
                 (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()) ); 

GLchar * code1 = (GLchar *) malloc(sizeof(GLchar) * str1.length());
strcpy(code1, str1.c_str());
```

Previously I was getting an "expression musy have class type" error on str1 variable after this version of the line:

```
std::string str1(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(filestream1), 
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() ); 
//str1 causes "expression must have class type" errors
```

Clearly, adding extra brackets (which seemed redundant to me, to be honest), fixed the problem. Question is, what exactly changed between one and the other? This isn't one of those "declaring a function instead of instantiating a class" mistakes, is it? I mean can one even declare a function with no name and inside a function call, and no [] like a lambda?

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://ideone.com/MWkUXy) Perhaps more context is required? Compiler and version?

Comment: Off-top: `str1.length()` doesn't include `'\0'`. Try `str1.length() + 1`. And, maybe `std::copy`/`std::copy_n`? Is `GLchar` always equal to `char`?

Comment: Fixed the lenght of buffer, duh, thanks! GLchar is defined as `typedef char GLchar;`, so I think yes, unless it changes in next lib versions.